# How to call portions of Magento into an external CMS, such as "item's in cart" or a "login form" in 1.4

Tags: magento, expressionengine

I know this is a question that has been discussed over and over, but I seem to be having trouble still.

Can anyone point me to the right direction, where I can learn to pull items from Magento, and display them in my EE pages?

I'll need to access magento from outside it's folder. Currently, EE is installed to the root, and Magento is installed in a sub. It's for a clothing store and I'd like to preserve the layout we currently have, and build upon it rather than abandon it for Magento's built in 'cms'.

Thanks guys, sorry if this has been asked before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of thing [the SOAP api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction) was built for.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I'll be getting my hands dirty with soap.

Comment: I've asked another question regarding Magento and SOAP - but maybe I can be a little more direct here - Can you give me a link to where I can begin to learn more about calling info from magento? I've successfully logged in to magento using SOAP and used an echo to display the user session ID.

I think I'm off to a good start-